# Prestashop - Lining up elements

Tags: html, css, prestashop

Been trying to line up the price and "Visa" button bor some time now without success so I thought I should ask stack for help.

This is how it looks like now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M78kf.png Not allowed to post image.

And this is the HTMl snippet:

```
                      <div class="product_price" style="margin-top: 25px; border: solid black 1px;">
                       {if isset($product.product->show_price) && $product.product->show_price AND !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                            <span class="price" style="border: solid black 1px;">
                               {if !$priceDisplay}
                                   {convertPrice price=$product.price_tax_inc}
                               {else}
                                   {convertPrice price=$product.product->price}
                               {/if}
                           </span>

                           {if $product.reduction && isset($product.reduction)}
                               <span class="original_price">
                                   {convertPrice price=$product.price_without_reduction}
                               </span>
                           {/if}

                           {/if}

                            <a class="exclusive button ajax_add_to_cart_button btn_add_cart view-the-product" href="{$link->getProductLink($product.product)}" style="max-width: 35px; border: solid black 1px; display: inline;"><span>{l s='Visa'}</span></a>

                        </div>
```

What style should I use to get "Visa" to line up with the price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set both of them the **display** value to inline-block, **float** them left and add the same **height**. Then the spacing could set by the **padding** value.

Please try this code:

```
span.price, a.ajax_add_to_cart_button {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
}
span.price {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
a.ajax_add_to_cart_button {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: It worked thanks! I have Another question: What is the default "add to cart" link in PrestaShop?

Comment: I am sorry I am not familiar with prestashop, you could open a new thread for that.